# Why does "git show HEAD~" show me the 3rd commit in my "git log" list?

Tags: git

I have a regular commit sandwiched in between two merge commits:

```
commit dc79715411f87e4a4c42c38559ba56ea911a0c01 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 097a551 415f5d1
Author: <redacted>
Date:   Tue Aug 14 11:29:54 2018 -0400

    Merge pull request #119 from <redacted>/th-dumb-init

    Use dumb-init instead of phusion

commit 415f5d183dcbf48fb5d27714112308f965438695
Author: <redacted>
Date:   Mon Aug 13 16:13:52 2018 -0400

    Use dumb-init instead of phusion

commit 097a5518087219327ed9f6f3a4499d54a1450cc2
Merge: 9aec35a b63cd1f
Author: <redacted>
Date:   Tue Jul 24 11:01:52 2018 -0400

    Merge pull request #118 from <redacted>/emails_off

    Turn off email alerts for 'orders_populate_every_five_min' Airflow job
```

When I run `git show HEAD`, I see the following:

```
[ sc-airflow ] $ git show HEAD
commit dc79715411f87e4a4c42c38559ba56ea911a0c01 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 097a551 415f5d1
Author: <redacted>
Date:   Tue Aug 14 11:29:54 2018 -0400

    Merge pull request #119 from <redacted>/th-dumb-init

    Use dumb-init instead of phusion
```

This is as I'd expect, since `HEAD` is currently pointing toward SHA `dc79715411f87e4a4c42c38559ba56ea911a0c01`.

However, when I type `git show HEAD~`, I see the following:

```
[ sc-airflow ] $ git show HEAD~
commit 097a5518087219327ed9f6f3a4499d54a1450cc2
Merge: 9aec35a b63cd1f
Author: <redacted>
Date:   Tue Jul 24 11:01:52 2018 -0400

    Merge pull request #118 from <redacted>/emails_off

    Turn off email alerts for 'orders_populate_every_five_min' Airflow job
```

This tells me `HEAD~` is pointing to SHA `097a5518087219327ed9f6f3a4499d54a1450cc2`.  However, I would expect `HEAD~` to refer to the commit just behind `HEAD`, or SHA `415f5d183dcbf48fb5d27714112308f965438695`.  Why is this not the case?

**EDIT:**
Running `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate` shows the following:

```
*   dc79715 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #119 from <redacted>/th-dumb-init
|\  
| * 415f5d1 Use dumb-init instead of phusion
|/  
*   097a551 Merge pull request #118 from <redacted>/emails_off
```

Comment: Run `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate`.

Comment: Updated the question with the output of the command you mentioned.

Comment: Note that, as described in the accepted answer, `097a551` is the "first" parent of `dc79715`, while `415f5d1` is the "second" parent. Neither of the two parents precede the other. In theoretical terms, `git log` gives you a topological sort of the directed acyclic graph formed by the commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git's `git log` command shows you commits in some order.  OK, so far that's obvious, but here's the tricky part: what order is that?

The *first* commit that `git log` shows is a *merge commit*.  That means it has two parents.  For convenience, let's call them "Mom" and "Dad" :-) .  So, having shown you that commit, now Git will show you Mom first.  Or maybe Dad first!  Which one will it show?  The default is: *show the younger (newer) commit*.

We know that `HEAD~1` is commit `097a5518087219327ed9f6f3a4499d54a1450cc2`.  That's the *first parent*, by parent-order—let's call this one `Dad` since `D` comes before `M`.  It may not be the first *commit*, by *commit date* order, though.  If Mom is younger than Dad, `git log` shows Mom after `HEAD`.  Then Mom has a parent, and if it turns out that Mom's parent is younger than Dad, Git shows you *that* commit next.  Only when it gets to the point where Dad is the next commit to show, does it show Dad.

There are sorting options to `git log` to tell it which commits to show, and when. Your best bet, though, us to use `git log --graph`—perhaps with `--oneline --decorate` as well—so that you can see the *commit graph*.  The `^` and `~` suffix operators are graph-followers, and do not look at the ages of the commits themselves.  The log-sorting *does* look at the ages of the commits by default, but stops doing so when you use `--graph`.